# How do I change the text of a TextArea

Tags: c#, webforms, textarea

I want to set the value of a `TextArea` on a HTML form using C#. I have tried this using `InnerText` property, but it keeps raising an exception:

> Esta propiedad no se admite en este tipo de HtmlElement."
>   (This property is not admitted in this type of HtmlElement)

This is the line that raises the exception:

```
form.Document.GetElementById(row["nombreCampo"].ToString()).InnerText = 
    row["valorCampo"].ToString();
```

And this is the code around it:

```
//recorro los formularios de la página
foreach (HtmlElement form in webBrowser1.Document.Forms)
{
    //recorro las filas del DataTable con los datos a autorellenar
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        //si conincide el nombre del campo con el nombre del DataTable, autorelleno
        if ((form.Document.GetElementById(row["nombreCampo"].ToString())!=null))
        {
            //para que ignore las minúsculas/mayúsculas
            if (form.Document.GetElementById(row["nombreCampo"].ToString())
                .Name.Equals("description", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
            {
                form.Document.GetElementById(row["nombreCampo"].ToString())
                    .InnerText = row["valorCampo"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                form.Document.GetElementById(row["nombreCampo"].ToString())
                    .SetAttribute("value", row["valorCampo"].ToString());
            }
        }//fin if
    }//fin foreach interno
}//fin foreach externo
```

I can not change the coda of the webpage, so that´s not an option.

[SOLVED]: I was trying to acces the wrong element because there are more than one elements named "description"

Answer (score 0):

Check out what type has such expression:

```
form.Document.GetElementById(row["nombreCampo"].ToString())
```

I think cast  is needed here.

Comment: It´s System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement  I tried cast, just in case, and it did not work.